# Is there any function in varnish to store a json/string data in cache or memory and reuse it in all requests?

Tags: caching, shared-memory, varnish

I am writing a varnish module which validates a HTTP request coming to my server and i have a JSON data dependency for my module. The Json data is taken by making a HTTP call from my module to redis server every dedicated interval time and store the JSON response into cache or Shared memory and use it. How do i achieve this with out disturbing the performance of varnish.

I have already tried Linux shared memory concept to store data and use it but I am hit with increase in varnish performance. I am seeing lot of http failures with this method when I was load testing. I would like to know how vanrish is caching http request and serving it to user, so that I can use the same method.

The logic of shared memory I am using is

```
if (memory exists){
    ...
    read memory and retrieve data
    ...
} else {
    make a call to server
    server responds with data
    store data in memory
}

...
use the data for request
...
```

The actual call to Server and retrieve data should happen once in interval time. It works well when tested manually. But failed when running load testing.. Seems to be child process issue where every child is accessing this piece of code and calling the server for every request.

I don't want to use mutex locks for this as it will decrease the performance.